# How to serialize Java generics with SimpleJson

Tags: java, generics, serialization, simplejson

I want to use a generic model to broadcast different data over websocket from server to client. Unfortunatley I always get an error while wanting to serialize the following class structure:

Class to be serialized using SimpleJson:

```
public class UpdateBroadcastMessageData {
    private List<UpdateBroadcastModel<? extends Object>> models = new ArrayList<UpdateBroadcastModel<? extends Object>>();

    public void clearModels() {
        ...
    }

    public void addModel(Object model) {
        ...
    }

    public void removeModel(Object model) {
       ...
    }
}

public class UpdateBroadcastModel<T extends Object> {
    private String clazz = null;
    private T payload = null;
    ...
}
```

My JsonUtil class throws always the message "Could not convert to JSon".

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonUtil {
    private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static String convertToJson(Object object) {
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not convert Object to JSON", e);
        return "";
    }
}

public static <T> T convertToObject(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not convert JSON to Object", e);
        return null;
    }
}
 }
```

Can somebody help me and tell me what to do to be able to serialize above datastructure?

The error refers to the converttoJson method. Here is the stacktrace:

```
ERROR [pool-3-thread-1][JsonUtil:16] Could not convert Object to JSON
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class 
...UpdateBroadcastMessageData and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer 
(to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider$1.serialize(StdSerializerProvider.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider._serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:296)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.StdSerializerProvider.serializeValue(StdSerializerProvider.java:224)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:1512)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:1262)
    at ...JsonUtil.convertToJson(JsonUtil.java:14)
    at ...CommitPoiTokenAction.doProcess(CommitPoiTokenAction.java:118)
    at ...BaseWebSocketTokenAction.processMessage(BaseWebSocketTokenAction.java:29)
    at ...WebSocketListener$1.run(WebSocketListener.java:145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
pool-3-thread-1: code=81 len=118
```

Thanks in advance.
faiko

Comment: Which method fails - is it convertToJson or convertToObject? Can you add the exception stacktrace?

Comment: i added the stacktrace above. It fails in convertToJson

Comment: Do you have getter / setter methods (properties) in these classes. Jackson by default uses the getter methods to serialize java objects to json and setter methods to do the reverse.  From the exception it looks like the class doesn't have any getter / setter methods.

Comment: aaahhh that solved my problem... i just forgot to declare the getter and setter in UpdateBroadcastMessageData for the list models...

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `ObjectMapper` inside the methods instead of class.

As you can see in your stacktrace, your error is caused by `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper...` when it is trying to serialize. If you don't declare it on methods, you have no object mapper, because you are not instantiating your object with a constructor and then you have no mapper.

```
public static String convertToJson(Object object) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();        
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not convert Object to JSON.", e);
    }
}

public static <T> T convertToObject(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(json, clazz);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not convert JSON to Object.", e);
    }
}
```

I must suggest you to catch your exceptions in a better way. If your application is throwing an error, you must throw that error and not ignore it. Use `throw new RuntimeException("Could not convert JSON to <whatever>", e);`

**UPDATE**

Don't forget to declare getters/setters in your classes.

Comment: @faiko Still throwing the same exception? I just saw right now that you forgot to declare setters and getters. Try declaring them.

Comment: aaahhh that solved my problem... i just forgot to declare the getter and setter in UpdateBroadcastMessageData for the list models... thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use java beans to serialize your Object. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans .

In fact,

> The class must have a public default constructor (with no-arguments). This allows easy instantiation within editing and activation frameworks.
>
> The class properties must be accessible using get, set, is (used for boolean properties instead of get), and other methods (so-called accessor methods and mutator methods) according to a standard naming convention. This allows easy automated inspection and updating of bean state within frameworks, many of which include custom editors for various types of properties. Setters can have one or more than one argument.
>
> The class should be serializable. [This allows applications and frameworks to reliably save, store, and restore the bean's state in a manner independent of the VM and of the platform.]

So, your class `UpdateBroadcastMessageData` must correspond to those criterias.